# Java Pageable - Each page different date starting from today

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

So I want to return a pageable that contains appointments. Each page in the pageable should contain only the appointments happening on one day. Page 0 should be Today's date and the next page will be all appointments taking place tomorrow, and it continues based on the amount of pages requested.

If you request 3 pages you will get all the appointments from today upto the day after tomorrow, each day in its own page.

I'm using the following:

- Spring Boot application
- JPARepository
- MySQL database

This is how my service implement looks:

```
public Page<Appointment> PageAppointments(int page, int size) throws RestException{

    Pageable limit = new PageRequest(page, size);
    return appointmentRepository.findAllByOrderByAppointmentDateDesc(limit);

}
```

This is how my repository looks:

```
public interface AppointmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Appointment, Long> {

    Page<Appointment> findAllByOrderByAppointmentDateDesc(Pageable pageable);

}
```

The result im looking for is something like this: (Conceptual)

```
//All Appointments taking place today
Page 1: {
    Appointment Entity with date 2017/07/22 11:19
    Appointment Entity with date 2017/07/22 14:08
    Appointment Entity with date 2017/07/22 15:21
    Appointment Entity with date 2017/07/22 16:44
}

//All Appointments taking place tomorrow
Page 2: {
    Appointment Entity with date 2017/07/23 11:19
    Appointment Entity with date 2017/07/23 14:08
    Appointment Entity with date 2017/07/23 15:21
    Appointment Entity with date 2017/07/23 15:34
    Appointment Entity with date 2017/07/23 16:11
    Appointment Entity with date 2017/07/23 16:44
}

//All Appointments taking place the day after tomorrow
Page 3: {
    Appointment Entity with date 2017/07/24 11:19
    Appointment Entity with date 2017/07/24 14:08
}
```

Then in this scenario if I request page 4 I'm supposed to get back all the appointments for 3 days from today which would be 2017/07/25 .

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Pageable as standard page predicate as you need a very custom pager.
You can use Pageable and Page only as wrapper for web level.

Main concerns: 
Pageable  is used as extra predicate in where section as limits and offset.In you case you don't have limit as you want to show all data for date in N-th page. Also you don't have offset as in your case offset = date.

You need couple queries that you wrap into PageImpl.

List content = dao.loadAllAppointmentsForDate(date);
Pageable pageable = new CustomePageRequest(.....);
long total = dao.countUniqueDateForAppointments();
Page page = new PageImpl(content ,pageable ,total );

you need create CustomePageRequest (implement Pageable interface)and overide `next(),previous(),first() , getPageNumber(),getPageSize().....` as by default they use page size for calulation curent , prev and next page , in your case you need ,propably, do some logical mapping like today=0 page , tomorrow =1 page day after tomorrow = 2....